# Weird issue with padding and whitespace: nowrap in Chrome and IE

Tags: html, css

I ran into really weird issue. ( http://jsfiddle.net/Fq68D/ )

HTML

```
<div>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
}
p {
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding:10%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

In Firefox it works like expected, text fits in p, and has padding,

While in Chrome and IE text gets out of box.

[image]

What causes this? Any workarounds?

Comment: This has to do with the padding percentage.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320934/quirky-percentage-interpretation-in-webkit

Comment: If I load your fiddle I see the issue, yet when I click run it corrects itself.

Comment: @j08691, weird, same happens when you inspect p element in chrome, and disable, then re-enable padding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to **`p`** element:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fq68D/1/

Comment: Thanks! this solves p sizing, but div is still smaller than p, and when I add overflow:hidden to div, p cuts off... is there any way to fix this one? The whole point of this code, is to make div display correcty.

Comment: When you change `%` to for example `px` unit then all is fine. I think  it's ok. Lets look on it. `p` have 10% padding. It need be calculated based on parent element `div`. In this case div doesn't have width. This width is based on p width but without padding. I hope you understand what I mean :)

Comment: Your answer made situation clear, but now, as I understand, it's impossible to accomplish what I need in Webkit and IE. And what I need is to get inline-block element, dimensions of which must be same as its child element, including child's percent-based padding(or margin)

Comment: I am happy, that my answer help you. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Use `width:fit-content;`
fixed my issue